# Cómo cargar un archivo plano (txt o Json) en un datagridView en C# con Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

Buen día gente, necesito ayuda para cargar un archivo (txt o Json) que contiene información con estructuras JSON, para mostrarlo en un `DataGridView` desde Windows Forms, posteriormente debo insertar esa información en una tabla (SQL)

El archivo posee las siguientes clases generadas desde Visual Studio:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string callControllerIP { get; set; }
    public string callControllerType { get; set; }
    public string ccid { get; set; }
    public int sessionDuration { get; set; }
    public string sessionId { get; set; }
    public long sessionStartDate { get; set; }
    public string sessionState { get; set; }
    public Track[] tracks { get; set; }
    public Urls urls { get; set; }
}

public class Urls
{
    public string httpUrl { get; set; }
    public string mp4Url { get; set; }
    public string rtspUrl { get; set; }
    public string wavUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public string codec { get; set; }
    public string downloadUrl { get; set; }
    public Participant[] participants { get; set; }
    public int trackDuration { get; set; }
    public string trackMediaType { get; set; }
    public int trackNumber { get; set; }
    public long trackStartDate { get; set; }
}

public class Participant
{
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string deviceRef { get; set; }
    public bool isConference { get; set; }
    public int participantDuration { get; set; }
    public long participantStartDate { get; set; }
    public string xRefCi { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Esta respuesta te puede ayudar (inglés)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/5622844).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes un json y las clases que mapean con este podrias usar el

[JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

basicamente seria

```
Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

no recuerdo si el json puede ser la ruta de un archivo, pero sino podrias usar

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("ruta");
```

y el contenido se lo pasas a json.net, de esta forma deserializas un json a clases